# Responsive design works on desktop but not iphone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, responsive

I am using a free theme for WordPress. I have customized the design to meet my needs, but there are problems with the design when i open the website using my iPhone or iPad. I have tried everything i know. Can someone help me identify the source of this problem? [Link of my website.][1]

Comment: By problem i mean the big empty space that shows before the header and nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this media query for **iPhone 6/6 Plus and Apple Watch CSS** media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px)
 and (max-device-width: 667px)
 and (orientation: landscape)
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
 { }
```

**iPhone 6 portrait**

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 375px)
and (max-device-width: 667px)
and (orientation: portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ }
```

**iPhone 6 Plus landscape**

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 414px)
and (max-device-width: 736px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{ }
```

**iPhone 6 Plus portrait**

```
 @media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 414px) 
and (max-device-width: 736px) 
and (orientation: portrait)
```

and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{ }

**iPhone 6 and 6 Plus**

```
  @media only screen
  and (max-device-width: 640px),
  only screen and (max-device-width: 667px),
  only screen and (max-width: 480px)
   { }
```

**Apple Watch**

```
  @media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
   and (min-device-width: 38mm)
  { }
```

For Image responsive

```
img {

   max-width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. The iPhone view looks perfectly fine when i look it up using tools like [http://quirktools.com/screenfly/] but still does not work on the real iPhone view. Do have any suggestion for a good simulator?

Comment: you should ensure all the images are also responsive. for image responsive  kindly check  the above post at end.

Comment: You have to make responsive slider images and reduce the font size if you are using dynamic text inside the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the responsive meta tag?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`  or `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`